# Integral equation $f(x) - \int_0^x f(t)dt = 0$

Tags: integral-equations

I'd like to know the solution (if solvable) to the following integral equation $$f(x) - \int_0^x f(t)dt = 0$$ Also I'd like to know what is the required mathematical background to be able to find a solution to this kind of equations by myself, I'm studying some topology at the moment and have studied calculus (single and some multivariable) and ordinary differential equations...so how far am I to begin solving integral equations?

Comment: Can you solve $\frac{d}{dx}F(x) - F(x) = 0$?

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle{{\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right) - \int_{0}^{x}{\rm f}\left(\, t\,\right)\,{\rm d}t = 0}$ ?.

Comment: K*e^x (K real)......thanks!!! i didn't notice it

Comment: wait, that's a solution to the differential equation .....not to the integral because of the K

Comment: Does it not imply then that K=0 and therefore $f(x)=0$

Comment: Yes Peter Brown ... thanks

Comment: Yes Felix Martin...it is $f(x) - \int_0^x f(t)dt = 0$, sorry for the late response and for the mistake

Comment: Can someone suggest me a good book to learn to solve integral equations?....if you think i'm still not able to study the topic, tell me what else do i need to know or other required background

Comment: The integral equation in this question is a very special case of one that can be reduced to a differential equation. More general integral equations, like Fredholm or Volterra equations, are probably out of your reach until you're much more experienced with analysis, at least up to functional analysis.